# regex for matching only commas inside square brackets

Tags: regex

I've some text like this:

```
umbrella12-2ndfloor-a,b,d (34) [bar, foo, coo], umbrella13-2ndfloor-a,d,e [bar], ...
```

I need to write a regex to match the comma which are inside the square brackets only.

Answer (score 0):

Use a look ahead that means "the next square bracket found must be a close bracket:

```
,(?=[^\[]*])
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/wn8tjAozLzrfwb).

Comment: `,(?=[^\[]*\])` worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this answered your question, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.